# Anchor Link to WooCommerce Reviews

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, woocommerce

The anchor link which scrolls down to the "Woocommerce Reviews Tab" is not working correctly.

```
<div class="woocommerce-product-rating">
        <?php echo wc_get_rating_html( $average, $rating_count ); ?>
        <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?><a href="#tab-reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">(<?php printf( _n( '%s customer review', '%s customer reviews', $review_count, 'woocommerce' ), '<span class="count">' . esc_html( $review_count ) . '</span>' ); ?>)</a><?php endif ?>
    </div>
```

[Link to Product](http://peelaway.co.za/product/25-tca-peel/)

I have checked that the link is displaying the correct anchor, which is 
[Link to Review Tab](http://peelaway.co.za/product/25-tca-peel/#tab-reviews)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the review div is hidden. if you click on review tab first and then you click on the link it will work.

I think you need to link to review tab with id "tab-title-reviews"

```
<div class="woocommerce-product-rating">
        <?php echo wc_get_rating_html( $average, $rating_count ); ?>
        <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?><a href="#tab-title-reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">(<?php printf( _n( '%s customer review', '%s customer reviews', $review_count, 'woocommerce' ), '<span class="count">' . esc_html( $review_count ) . '</span>' ); ?>)</a><?php endif ?>
    </div>
<script>
jQuery('.woocommerce-review-link').click(function(){
    jQuery('#tab-title-reviews a').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

Comment: This change does make it scroll, however does not open the reviews tab - it opens the 'description' tab?

Comment: I told you that you need a custom js code to achieve this